# How to use libc's listxattr in python code?

Tags: python, glibc

I'm a python newbie, I want to parse all the extended attributes of a file and perform some operation if it matches a particular pattern.
For Ex.  I have to search for attributes of the pattern user.thing* like user.thing1 user.thing2 etc. and I have to perform some operations based on the matching.
In C I can do a listxattr and if the a particular key has the pattern I wish for I can do a getxattr on the same.
How to accomplish the same in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [xattr](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xattr) package.

```
$ easy_install xattr
$ python
>>> import xattr
>>> dict(xattr.xattr('.'))
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is really old, but just to update, python 3 has [os.listxattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listxattr)